# How to show ExitDialog after progress dialog

Tags: wix

my installer only contains one dialog now, which is the progress dialog. I want to add a exit dialog after progress, then I can know the installer is completed explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

In **InstallUISequence** add reference to show exit dialog on success

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="MyExitDialog" OnExit="success" />
</InstallUISequence>
```

Comment: do I need define MyExitDialog at first? because occurred error when i used 'ExitDlg'

Comment: Yes you have to define MyExitDialog if you are not using the exit dialog provided by the WIX...you can go through this link for more details...(http://www.dizzymonkeydesign.com/blog/misc/adding-and-customizing-dlgs-in-wix-3/)